# slice path with RewritCond and check if third segment exist as a folder on the drive

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I’m searching the good RewriteCond in apache httpd 2.4 to slice URL path and check if the third segment of the path can correspond to a  folder name on my drive

The RewriteCond must work for **all** those examples:

a) server.mydomain.com/bar/foo/folder1/

b) server.mydomain.com/bar/foo/folder1

c) server.mydomain.com/bar/foo/folder1/bee/other

I want to check if folder /tmp/folder1 exist on server drive

I have tested this, but  it's not working for b) and c)

```
RewriteCond (%REQUEST_URI) ^/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/

RewriteCond /tmp/%3 -d

RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://server2.mydomain.com/$1
```

thanks for your help
Joe

Comment: `/tmp/folder1` is relative to your DocumentRoot or absolute file system path?

Comment: this is an absolute path.

Comment: `(%REQUEST_URI)` isn't an apache predefined variable and your server is treating it as `plain text` . Change it to `%{REQUEST_URI}` if that's not a typo.

Answer (score 0):

ok I found that solution and it's working:

RewriteCond %(REQUEST_URI) ^/bar/foo/([^/]+)/ [NC,OR]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/bar/foo/(.*)$ [NC]

RewriteCond /tmp/%1 -d

RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://server2.mydomain.com/$1